# How To Redirect Requests For a Resource That Are Not on The Server?

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, ubuntu-14.04, request-filtering

How to redirect requests for a resource that are not on the server ? ,
i have a website hosted on ubuntu 14.04 - apache 2.4 i want my website to accept only requests for files on the server and the others redirect them to another website , can that done ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple in Apache HTTPD 2.4 with the new If Directive, you can check if the file does not exist and then redirect accordingly like this:

```
<If "! -f '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}'">
    Redirect / http://example.com/
</If>
```

This checks the request is a normal file and exists, if it doesn't it will redirect those requests to example.com/ or whatever domain you specify.

If you just need to Redirect to the other domain without specifying the initial request made by the client, then use this redirect inside the If, instead of the other:

```
RedirectMatch ^ http://example.com/
```

You can check all about the If direcitve in the HTTPD Docs: [If][1]

You can check all about the format of expressions in the HTTPD Docs: [Expressions in Apache HTTPD Server][2]

- [1]: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if
- [2]: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

Comment: Files do not matter in Apache HTTPD, only context. You can place that in VirtualHost context, that is, your VirtualHost.

Comment: You can not use variables with Redirect. In your question you didn't say anything specifically about the other server, just that you wanted to redirect to another server. And that's what the If + Redirect does.
Also I don't think you know what ${REQUEST_URI} does because it does not specify a Host in it.

Comment: Your comments have dissapeared?

Comment: sorry , what i want is what you mentiond in the first .

Comment: i want to redirect the complete url request with parameters and every thing to another server if the file that in the request is not on the main server of the request

Comment: i tried the first code but didn't work for me it return with 404 of my server and didn't redirect the request ..

Comment: You didn't place it in the correct context, Ive tested this.

Comment: i putted in 000-default.conf in after <VirtualHost *:80>

Comment: try "curl -I http://yourip/doesnotexist" and see the headers you get. Make sure you restarted apache after changing the config.

Comment: thanks man , it worked after while without making any change ..

Comment: that was probably your browsers cache playing tricks on you ;)

Comment: yeah i guess so :D

Comment: That's why I said to use curl earlier, because it does not use cache and you always get the real response from the server.

Comment: really good answers  , i was looking for information like that for my projects ..